# Python groupby error, 'unhashable' Series object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of values (floats) and country name strings ("UNITED STATES", "UNITED KINGDOM", etc).  I want to sum the values based on the countries:

```
Data['Values'].groupby(Data['Country']).sum()
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Also, if I try to unique the Series consisting of the countries:

```
Data['Country'].unique()
```

I get the same error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Why is this error occurring?  Is it something about the country names?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am using Python 3.4 and Pandas 0.15.2.

Comment: I think your approach is a little different than most, but this should still work.  if you do a Data['Country'].dtype what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I get:  dtype('O')

Comment: @crow_t_robot, true, I haven't paid enough attention to see your error, although not correct to groupby using `Data['Values']`, you should get **KeyError** instead. Can you show what `type(Data)` is?

Comment: type(Data) gives me "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame".  Even using Data instead of Data['Values'] produces the same TypeError, however.

Comment: Then we should logically check what's your another column's dtype and see if we can find the cause

Comment: There may be some illegal escape character in your **Country** column, can you verify that?

Comment: what happens when you set `Data.Country = Data.Country.apply(str)`? I don't know how, but it looks to me like you have a Series containing Series.

Comment: @ari : Bingo.  Applying str allows me to groupby properly.  Post as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes mutable types like lists (or Series in this case) can sneak into your collection of immutable objects.

You can use `apply` to force all your objects to be immutable. Try

```
Data.Country = Data.Country.apply(str)
Data.groupby('Country').Values.sum()
```

Note that this can result in strings not being what you expected them to be; e.g. `str(['Canada'])` -> `"['Canada']"` so `str(['Canada']) == 'Canada'` will yield `False`. I recommend doing `Data.Country.unique()` and at least visually inspecting to make sure that everything looks as it should.

Comment: Exactly right.  I had a Series object within the list of country strings.  Don't end up like me, kids.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but maybe the better option would be to figure out why there is series object in your list and remove it. In my case, it was some duplication.